# Is it okay to for the integrand and bounds of integration to be functions of the same variable?

Tags: notation

For the sake of simplicity, say we given that $a = 6t$ and that we must find the velocity as a function of time. We would set up the following integral:

$$\displaystyle \int_{v(t_0)}^{v(t)}dv = \int_{t_0}^t 6t\,dt$$

Having $t$ in the bounds of integration and also in the integrand seems weird to me. Is this the best way to notate it?

Answer (score 1):

Very bad mathematical grammar. It's perhaps comprehensible, but can lead to horrible errors. Don't do it!

Write
$$
\int_0^t 6 \tau\, d \tau.
$$

Comment: Say I'm deriving the equation $v_x^2=v_0^2+2a \Delta x$. We end up getting $v\,dv=a\,dx$. Would the following be a suitable notation? $\int_{v_0}^{v_x} \nu \, d\nu = \int_{x_0}^{x}a \, d\chi$. More generally, should we replace the variable we're integrating with respect to with its Greek analog?

Comment: I tend to do that, as in my example ---  but writing  $\int_0^x x'\,dx'$ is also fine. Note that the greek "x" is $\xi$, and not $\chi$!

Comment: Hmm... and the Greek "$v$" is not $\nu$. Would $u$ would be more appropriate?

Comment: The modern greek letter that is pronounced "v" is $\beta$, and maybe that is why $\beta$ is used for $v/c$ in relativity.